# Template specialization unmatched error

Tags: c++

### Re-edited:

Here's what *C++ Primer 5th* says:

Version 1:

`template <typename T> int compare(const T&, const T&);`

Version 2:

`template<size_t N, size_t M> int compare(const char (&)[N], const char (&)[M]);`

A specialization of Version 1:

`template <> int compare(const char* const &p1, const char* const &p2);`

> For example, we have defined **two versions** of our `compare` function template, **one that takes references to array parameters** and **the other that takes** `const T&`. The fact that we **also have a specialization for character pointers** has no impact on function matching. When we call compare on a string literal: `compare("hi", "mom")`
> **both function templates are viable and provide an equally good (i.e., exact) match to the call.** However, the version with **character array parameters** is more specialized (§ 16.3, p. 695) and is chosen for this call.

---

The book says "both provide an equally good match", so then I thought putting Version 1 and its specialization should compile well. But it didn't.

So "provide an equally good match" doesn't mean it can compile? The book plays a trick on me?

Original code snippet link that I didin't understand why can't compile:
https://wandbox.org/permlink/oSCDWad03nELC9xs

---

Full context screenshot (I've boxed the most related part, sorry to post such a big pic here).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Take a look at the error you get, and remember that literal strings are really *arrays* (which are quite clearly indicated in the error message).

Comment: @Rick Consider re-reading the error message with notes: "_deduced conflicting types for parameter 'const T' ('char [3]' and 'char [4]')_".

Comment: Your code only contains version 1 and version 3 of the function. Version 2 from the book (`template<size_t N, size_t M> int compare(const char (&)[N], const char (&)[M]); // second version to handle string literals`) is missing.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. The book shows working code. You removed some of that code and it stopped working. Why do you think the book is wrong?

Comment: @Rick Consider re-reading the chapter. When the book states "Both function templates are viable and provide an equally good match to the call", it is talking about the the original template function, and the template specialization which takes character array. It is, however, **not** talking about "both function template _specializations_".

Comment: Bad book. The worst possible way to explain function template overloading vs. specialization.

Comment: @Rick Re-read the paragraph just prior to the marked one. "For example, we have defined two versions of our `compare` function template, one that takes references to array parameters, and the other that takes `const T&`". As you can see, there's no mention of the second specialization of `compare`.

Comment: Note that this is one reason overloading a function template with a non-template function is almost always what you actually want, and function template specializations are rarely useful.

Comment: @melpomene I re-edited the question. The book says putting Version 1 and its specialization together, which is a "an equally good match". So that's why I think the orignal code should compile well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C-style strings are not pointers, they are arrays.  When template type deduction happens, it deduces `T` as either `const char[3]` or `const char[4]`.  Since those conflict the compiler is unable to deduce `T` and it stops there.

```
template<>
int compare(const char* const &p1, const char* const&p2) {
    cout << "const char* const" << endl;
    return 3;
}
```

won't be called because it relies on `T` being deduced and matching `const char*` and the compiler was not able to deduce `T`.  A specialization is not a overload, it is a recipe for that specific `T`.  If `T` can't be deduced then the specialization, even it it were to be a valid overload, won't be called.

If you were to overload the function instead of providing a specialization [then it would compile](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GXHLHQwynbxPAOg8) with:

```
int compare(const char* const &p1, const char* const&p2) {
    cout << "const char* const" << endl;
    return 3;
}
```

Comment: @Rick It is but it still requires `T` to be deduced to be able to call it.  `template<> int compare(const char* const &p1, const char* const&p2)` has a `T` of `const char*` so it will only be called if `T` is deduced as such and sine deduction fails it will never call it.

Comment: Thank you. I re-edited the question. But I still feel confused about why the book has to say "both provide an equally good match", while merely putting Version 1 and its specialization can't compile, the deduction would fail as you describe. The specialization is totally useless here. I think the book plays a trick on me.. 

Comment: @Rick The book is wrong.  `template <typename T> int compare(const T&, const T&);` will never work with `compare("hi", "mom");`.  That said, if you had `compare("mom", "dad")` then it would pick the array version instead of the general one.

Comment: With Version1  and the specialization, even providing `compare("mom", "dad")`, the specialization one still won't get called.
So for any circumstances, the specialization one of Version 1 will not get called.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing to the template function two parameters of **different types** (the type of `"hi"` is `const char [3]` and the type of `"mom"` is `const char [4]`), so the compiler is not able to find a `T` that matches both types.

It's the same error that you would obtain calling `std::min(0, 1U)`; `std::min()` (one of its overload) expects two arguments **of the same type**, as your `compare()` function does.

A possible *solution* to your problem is to accept parameters of different types:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
int compare(const T1&, const T2&);
```

This will work without editing the body of your function.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is unable to match it to one of the existing templates. If you read the section 16.5 carefully you will understand that it would call the second version of the template class.

The function call has 2 different types of parameters `const char[3]` and `const char [4]` compiler is unable to find a template specialization that takes 2 different data types as parameters.
The code below is one of the solutions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template <typename T> int compare(const T&, const T&) {
  cout << "const T" << endl;
  return 3;
}

template<size_t N, size_t M>
int compare(const char (&p)[N], const char (&q)[M]) {   
   cout<<p<<" "<<q<<endl;
   return 3;
}

int main()
{
   compare("hi", "mom");
}
```

The other solution is as below. It takes 2 different types and access the variables.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template <typename T> int compare(const T&, const T&) {
   cout << "const T" << endl;
   return 3;
}

template <typename T1, typename T2>
int compare(const T1&p, const T2&q){   
   cout<<p<<" "<<q<<endl;
   return 3;
}

int main()
{
   compare("hi", "mom");
}
```